# Different headers for different pages - Weasyprint PDF Generation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation, weasyprint

I am using **Weasyprint library (version - 52.2) in Python** to generate PDF. The following documents helps to add common header/footer for all the pages in the pdf.

> https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tips-tricks.html
> https://gist.github.com/nathandem/63f410d501d200cfa5613b38aaf74c44

The code calculates the height of header, footer ,and body and then it adjusts the margin based on the header's height.

However, my use-case is slightly different. I have no header for Page 1 and need to add a common header for the subsequent pages. Is there a way to change the margin for the first Page alone?

Comment: Can you add code where you use `PdfGenerator` class? (I have looked at both of links you provided, but I have never used Weasyprint library so I did't understnad how to create an instance of `PdfGenerator` and how to create pdf file using `PdfGenerator`.)